# Blas DGEMV input error

Tags: blas

I'm having trouble figuring out why a piece of blas call is throwing n error. The problem call is the last blas call. The code compiles without issue and runs fine up until this call then fails with the following message.

> ** ACML error: on entry to DGEMV  parameter number  6 had an illegal value

As far as I can tell everything the input types are correct and array a has 
I would really appreciate an insight into the problem.
Thanks

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cblas.h"
#include "array_alloc.h"

int main( void )
{
  double **a, **A;
  double  *b, *B, *C;

  int *ipiv;
  int n, nrhs;
  int info;
  int i, j;

  printf( "How big a matrix?\n" );
  fscanf( stdin, "%i", &n );

  /* Allocate the matrix and set it to random values but
     with a big value on the diagonal. This makes sure we don't
     accidentally get a singular matrix */
  a = alloc_2d_double( n, n );
  A= alloc_2d_double( n, n );

  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
      a[ i ][ j ] = ( ( double ) rand() ) / RAND_MAX;
    }
    a[ i ][ i ] = a[ i ][ i ] + n;
  }
  memcpy(A[0],a[0],n*n*sizeof(double)+1);


  /* Allocate and initalise b */
  b = alloc_1d_double( n );
  B = alloc_1d_double( n );
  C = alloc_1d_double( n );

  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    b[ i ] = 1;
  }

  cblas_dcopy(n,b,1,B,1);
  /* the pivot array */
  ipiv = alloc_1d_int( n );

  /* Note we MUST pass pointers, so have to use a temporary var */
  nrhs = 1;

  /* Call the Fortran. We need one underscore on our system*/
  dgesv_(  &n, &nrhs, a[ 0 ], &n, ipiv, b, &n, &info );

  /* Tell the world the results */
  printf( "info = %i\n", info );
  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    printf( "%4i ", i );
    printf( "%12.8f", b[ i ] );
    printf( "\n" );
  }

  /* Want to check my lapack result with blas */

cblas_dgemv(CblasRowMajor,CblasTrans,n,n,1.0,A[0],1,B,1,0.0,C,1);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading dimension (LDA) needs to be at least as large as the number of columns (n) for a RowMajor matrix. You’re passing a LDA of 1.

Separately, I’m slightly suspicious of your matrix types; without seeing how `alloc_2d_double` is implemented there’s no way to be sure if you’re laying out the matrix correctly or not.  Generally speaking, intermixing pointer-to-pointer-style “matrices” with BLAS-style matrices (contiguous arrays with row or column stride) is something of a code smell.  (However, it is *possible* to do correctly, and you may well be handling it properly; it’s just not possible to tell if this is the case from the code you posted).